# Mocked List using Mockito isEmpty always returns false, even if the size is 0

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm playing with Mockito (1.9.5) and stuck at first simple test case:

```
List mockedList = mock(ArrayList.class);
assertEquals(0, mockedList.size()); // Passed
assertTrue(mockedList.isEmpty()); // Failed
```

Can anyone explain why isEmpty() here returns false while the size() returns 0?

Comment: I know you are just playing about at this point, but List is a bad thing to be mocking. It is already well tested, easy to set up (Arrays.asList for example) and not dependent on external resources. It is (as you have already seen) easy to build a mocked List in an invalid state, something that would not happen is you used a real list.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this happens because mockito doesn't know the semantic meaning of `isEmpty()` and when it encounters a boolean method mocks it with a default value that is `false`. Same think happens with `size()` but the default value here is `0`.

Basically, you need to define the expected behaviour of your mocked object. If you don't, it will return default values.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I have to use `when(mockedList.isEmpty()).thenReturn(true);` to stub the `mockedList`. Thanks!